# Joi - is it possible to reference multiple values?

Tags: javascript, joi

Struggling to find anything about this in the docs - is it possible to reference multiple values?

Say I have a schema that takes 3 numbers (`a`, `b`, `c`), is it possible to set a `max` property on `c` based on `a` and `b`. Something like the following:

```js
joi.object().keys({
  a: joi.number(),
  b: joi.number(),
  c: joi.number().max(joi.ref('a') + joi.ref('b'))
})
```

Comment: If you pass anything via an object, it gets referenced

Comment: @tbhaxor could you elaborate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Javascript pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference)

Comment: https://medium.com/nodesimplified/javascript-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript-fcf10305aa9c

Comment: @tbhaxor no... I am looking for answers for joi, the validation library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, multiple values use `expression` like

```
const schema = joi.object().keys({
  a: joi.number(),
  b: joi.number(),
  c: joi.expression("{{a +b}}"),
});
console.log(schema.validate({ a: 400, b: 300, c: 700 }));
```